# Recency and Frequency segmentaion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have generated recency and frequency output in csv format from my RFM model. I wanted to segment that output in this manner;

```
1) Recency

R1  Between 181 and 360 days
R2  Between 121 and 180 days
R3  Between 61 and 120 days
R4  Between 31 and 60 days
R5  Last 30 days
```

For frequency,

```
2) Frequency (number of purchases in the last 12 months):

F1  1 time
F2  Between 2 and 5 times
F3  Between 6 and 9 times
F4  Between 10 and 11 times
F5  12 times or more
```

I am not able to find a solution on how to create two new columns  with above ouputs.

this is my sample data;

df_rf->

```
frequency     recency
1               179
1               158
1               61
2                82
2               314
```

Output should be like this,

```
frequency    recency     Frequency_label                   Recency_label
1               179           F1                           R2
1               158           F1                           R2
1                 61           F1                          R3
2                82            F2                          R3
2                314           F2                          R1
```

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for the support!

Answer (score 2):

Not to take anything away from @Sonia Samipillai's answer, which looks good (and I'm glad you got the help you needed!), but I wanted to show another way of accomplishing the same thing which might make for neater code overall, especially in cases with lots of values to replace like this one.

For this we define the substitutions we want to make within some dictionaries and then turn to [pandas' between() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html?highlight=between#pandas.Series.between).

In this case (assuming you wanted to keep the original columns and add the new versions -- otherwise it would be that much simpler!), I think I would write something like:

```
import numpy as np

freq_cat_mapping = {(1, 1): 'F1', (2, 5): 'F2', (6, 9): 'F3', (10, 11): 'F4', (12,None,13): 'F5'}
frequency_cats = df_rf['frequency']
for range, value in freq_cat_mapping.items():
    if len(range) == 2:
        frequency_cats = np.where(df_rf['frequency'].between(*range), value, frequency_cats)
    else:
        # This got a bit messy since I had to improvise some Q&D logic to handle the open intervals...but it could obviously be improved.
        if range[-1] > range[0]:
            cond = df_rf['frequency'] >= range[0]
        else:
            cond = df_rf['frequency'] <= range[0]
        frequency_cats = np.where(cond, value, frequency_cats)

recency_cat_mapping = {(0, 30): 'R1', (31, 60): 'R2', (61, 120): 'R3', (121, 180): 'R4', (181, 360): 'R5'}
recency_cats = df_rf['recency']
for range, value in recency_cat_mapping.items():
    recency_cats = np.where(df_rf['recency'].between(*range), value, recency_cats)

#Finally, concatanate the new cols
df_rf['frequency_label'] = frequency_cats
df_rf['recency_label'] = recency_cats
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['frequency'] = [1,1,1,2,2]
df['recency'] = [179,158,61,82,314]


#Calculating Frequency labels 

df['Frequency_label'] = np.where((df['frequency'] <= 1), 'F1',
                                 np.where((df['frequency'] >= 2) & (df['frequency'] <= 5), 'F2',
                                          np.where((df['frequency'] >= 6) & (df['frequency'] <= 9), 'F3',
                                                   np.where((df['frequency'] >= 10) & (df['frequency'] <= 11), 'F4',
                                                            np.where((df['frequency'] >= 12), 'F5','NA') ) )))

# Calculating Recency labels
df['Recency_label'] = np.where((df['recency'] >= 181) & (df['recency'] <= 360), 'R1',
                                 np.where((df['recency'] >= 121) & (df['recency'] <= 180), 'R2',
                                          np.where((df['recency'] >= 61) & (df['recency'] <= 120), 'R3',
                                                   np.where((df['recency'] >= 31) & (df['recency'] <= 60), 'R4',
                                                            np.where((df['recency'] <= 30), 'R5','NA') ) )))
```

Output:

```
  frequency recency Frequency_label Recency_label
0   1       179      F1              R2
1   1       158      F1              R2
2   1       61       F1              R3
3   2       82       F2              R3
4   2       314      F2              R1
```

Comment: Thanks Sonia for your reply with a suggestion on how to derive an outcome. Sample data is certainly within my actual output. Just not sure how to apply the same logic in my dataframe though! I shall try and see if I get the right result

Comment: What are the columns in your data frame? Just substitute the number of days and number of purchases columns in the code above. It should work well.

Comment: here is my sample data :

frequency recency
 1     179
 1      158
 1      61
 2      82
 2      314

Comment: ok. Just substitute 'frequency' in the place of 'n_purchases' and 'recency' in the place of 'days'. Like for example, instead of df['n_purchases'] your code should have df['frequency'] and instead of df['days'] use df['recency']. You have to just substitute your column names.

Comment: thanks. I shall give it a go. Ive updated my actual question with sample data and desired output results

Comment: Edited the answer as per your data. Let me know if any questions. You got this!

Comment: Thanks! I've just tested this on my df and it worked like a treat.